TypScript compilation failed - Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to
I try to create dynamic tests based on an excel sheet with testcafe using TypeScript.
That works smooth... until I try to create the "tests" of the "fixture" dynamicly.
My code:
import { fixture, test, GFunctions } from './index';

fixture`API Testing with TestCafe`
.page`about:blank`;

// Assume testData is an array of test definitions
let gFunctionName: any = getFunctionName()
const testData: any = await getTestData(gFunctionName)

console.info(testData)

for (const data of testData) {

    test(`APITest: ${data.gFunctionName}`, async (t) => {
        // Initialisations
        const { token }: { token: any; } = await GFunctions.getAccessToken(t, gFunctionName);
        // const gfuctionResponse: any = await GFunctions.getParamsAndExecute(data.index, data.response, t, token, gFunctionName);
        // console.info('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', `Status: ${gfuctionResponse.status} >> ${data.result_status}`);
    });

}

function getFunctionName() {
return GFunctions.getGFunctionName(\__filename)
}
async function getTestData(gFunctionName: string) {
const { testData }: { testData: any } = await GFunctions.getTestDefinition(gFunctionName);
return testData;
}

Wenn running the Code i always get the following error:
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

Error: TypeScript compilation failed.
D:/Repositories/WAS_API-Testing/TestCafe/environments/fo-wastest-eshop-regression.was.local/tests/_gGetGlobalConfigVar.apitest.ts (9, 23): 
Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 
'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', 
and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

package.json:
{
    "type": "module",
    "name": "testcafe-tests",
    "description": "TestCafe-Tests",
    "version": "24.01.0",
    "scripts": {
        "TEST": "testcafe chrome:headless tests/_gGetGlobalConfigVar.apitest.ts --ts-config-path=./tsconfig.test.json -r spec,xunit:./reports/report.apitest.xml,html:reports/report.apitest.html"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
        "testcafe-reporter-html": "^1.4.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "testcafe": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "volta": {
        "node": "16.13.1"
    }
}

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // "target": "ES6",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "../../opacc_modules/"
    ]
}

tsconfig.test.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "module": "ES2020",
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.apitest.ts"
    ]
}

Does anyone have an idea how can resolve this? As I see it I do use the mentioned targe/module...?
Hopefully
Roman

Tried to edit the tsconfig.json itself --> seems not to be alowed...
You cannot override the "target" compiler option in the TypeScript configuration file.
You cannot override the "module" compiler option in the TypeScript configuration file.


As was mentioned in the message, you cannot override "target" and "module" compiler options in TestCafe.
But in order to use Top-level await expressions like yours
(const testData: any = await getTestData(gFunctionName)),
you can wrap the getTestData call in an Immediately Invoked Function expression.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE#execute_an_async_function

gonna try that! Thanx :)

This worked.
Sadly it seems that - when there are no test() routines at Top level Testcafe just ignores the code totally -.-
Gonna try around a bit more. If i cant get it running i will create a Main Test and execute the testdata within it as a whole.
Thanx

Error messages are usually useful:

Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to
'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext',
and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

Just follow the steps. Modify your tsconfig.jsons.

I did. But then - as mentioned - i got this message
You cannot override the "target" compiler option in the TypeScript configuration file. You cannot override the "module" compiler option in the TypeScript configuration file.
